# How to utilize .apply on functions from geopy in pandas when creating new column from existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, distance, latitude-longitude, geopy

So I am trying to find a more efficient way of doing a task I already made some code for. The purpose of the code is to use 4 columns (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, YORK_LATITUDE, YORK_LONGITUDE) to create a new column which calculates the distance between two coordinates in kilometers in a panda dataframe. Where the first coordinate is (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) and the second coordinate is (YORK_LATITUDE, YORK_LONGITUDE).

[A link of what the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/714D4.jpg)

In order to complete the task right now I create a list using the following code (geopy and pandas iterrows), convert that into a column and concatenate that to the dataframe. This is cumbersome, I know that there is an easier way to utilize .apply and the geopy function, but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax.

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic as GD
list = []
for index, row in result.iterrows():
    coordinate1 = (row['LATITUDE'], row['LONGITUDE'])
    coordinate2 = (row['LATITUDE_YORK_UNIVERSITY'], row['LONGITUDE_YORK_UNIVERSITY'])
    list.append(GD(coordinate1, coordinate2).km)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
df.apply(lambda x: distance(x[:2], x[2:]), axis=1)
```

### Some explanation

Let's say we have a function, which requires two tuples as arguments. For example:

```
from math import dist

def distance(point1: tuple, point2: tuple) -> float:
    
    # suppose that developer checks the type
    # so we can pass only tuples as arguments
    assert type(point1) is tuple
    assert type(point2) is tuple

    return dist(point1, point2)
```

Let's apply the function to this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.arange(10*4).reshape(10, 4),
    columns=['long', 'lat', 'Y long', 'Y lat']
)
```

We pass to `apply` two parameters: `axis=1` to iterate over rows, and a wrapper over `distance` as a lambda-function. To split the row in tuples we can apply `tuple(...)` or `(*...,), note the comma at the end in the latter option:

```
df.apply(lambda x: distance((*x[:2],), (*x[2:],)), axis=1)
```

The thing is that `geopy.distance` doesn't require exactly tuples as an arguments, they can be [any iterables with 2 to 3 elements](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/0c0e6e3d1179606107d9a0e71710f952dd4f5084/geopy/point.py#L462) (see the endpoint [how an argument is transformed](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/0c0e6e3d1179606107d9a0e71710f952dd4f5084/geopy/point.py#L169) into the inner type `Point` while [defining distance](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/0c0e6e3d1179606107d9a0e71710f952dd4f5084/geopy/distance.py#L555)). So we can simplify this to:

```
df.apply(lambda x: distance(x[:2], x[2:]), axis=1)
```

To make it independent from the columns order we could write this (in your terms):

```
common_point = ['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE']
york_point = ['LATITUDE_YORK_UNIVERSITY','LONGITUDE_YORK_UNIVERSITY']
result.apply(lambda x: GD(x[common_point], x[york_point]).km, axis=1)
```